# How to bar chart overlapping times in Excel for phone channels to find simultaneous number of calls at any given time?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

Object is to determine the highest number of channels (phone call channels) used during a 24 hour period, and then over a 7 day, and eventually over a few months period. This is needed to show us exactly how many MAXIMUM channels we are using in at any given peak time.

I would like to have a bar graph showing 1-100 in Y-axis and X-axis to be a 24 hour period or a 7 day or a 30 day etc...

Data sets we have are like this:

```
Date        Phone-Number    Time    Duration(in seconds)

2014-01-01  415-444-7777    10:10   180

2014-01-01  415-444-6666    10:11   60

2014-02-01  415-222-1111    6:35    800

2014-03-01  415-444-5555    10:20   400

2014-03-01  415-444-4444    10:22   45

2014-05-01  415-222-1112    11:00   354
```

Above example shows that `row1` and `row2` have an overlap between 10:11 to 10:12 so we want to show this on bar graph as 2-channels being used and anything before or after that as 1-channel being used. Same thing can be said about `row4` and `row5`.

Is this possible to do in Excel and if yes, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google using a horizontal bar graph to create a gantt chart, where each bars length is the call start and stop time. You can calculate the stop time by adding the duration to the time with a formula like this:

```
 TIMEVALUE("10:10:00 AM")+ TIME(0,0,180)
```

That gives you a start stop time by day for your chart.

On a worksheet you can use the formula to increment the time by one second so each row is a list of 1's representing the one second time increment in each column, then sum the 1's across the column to get the max number of channels for every second of overlap between calls.

The problem of counting overlapping seconds across multiple rows of calls requires a complex calculation that compares each second of a call against every second of all the other calls in the distribution to look for overlaps. (I solved a similar problem for looking for overlapping open long and short trades for the same security.)

Reply back if you want to tackle the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please give an example of what you mean in this part: **On a worksheet you can use the formula to increment the time by one second so each row is a list of 1's representing the one second time increment in each column, then sum the 1's across the column to get the max number of channels for every second of overlap between calls.**

Comment: Did my reply not get to you? I see my updates above in the solution, but you have not responded, or selected the answer as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have rethought the approach and offer the below as the solution.
Set up three tabs named CallTimes, CallList, And ScratchPad.
CallList will be where your raw data is pasted. (Like the above)
CallTimes will be the counts of each second from 8:00 AM to 8:00 PM.
You can adjust the time range in the code.
ScratchPad will be used to create a record for every 1 second increment from each call time found on the call list. So 10:10 with a duration of 180 seconds will create 181 records on Scratchpad, then move on to row 2, etc.
When the macro stops CallTimes will have the counts in column 2. You can add a max, function or autofilter or graph from there.

```
'
'  SetCallTimes -  creates a list of call times 1 second apart from 8:00 to 8:00
'
'
Public Function SetCallTimes()

    Dim dblTime As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tWS As Worksheet
    Dim sWS As Worksheet
    Dim ScratchPad As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sTimer As Single
    Dim strMsg As String

   Debug.Print Now()

    With Application
      .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     ' .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    With ActiveWorkbook
      Set tWS = .Sheets("CallTimes")
      Set sWS = .Sheets("CallList")
      Set ScratchPad = .Sheets("ScratchPad")
    End With

    With tWS.UsedRange
        .ClearContents
        .ClearFormats
        .Range("A1").Value = "Time"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Count"
    End With
    'Set start time
    dblTime = TimeValue("8:00:00")

    For i = 0 To (60 * 60 * 8)

       tWS.Range("A" & i + 2).Value = "'" & Format(DateAdd("s", i, dblTime), "HH:MM:SS")
       tWS.Range("B" & i + 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(ScratchPad!C[-1],RC[-1])"

    Next i

    With ScratchPad.UsedRange
      .ClearContents
      .ClearFormats
    End With
    With ScratchPad
      .Range("A1").Value = "Time"
      .Range("B1").Value = "Source"
      .Range("C1").Value = "DurationSecond"
    End With

    'F is the column with the starttime, G has the duration
    lRow = 1
    For Each aCell In Intersect(sWS.Range("F1").EntireColumn, sWS.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
      For i = 0 To aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
          lRow = lRow + 1
          ScratchPad.Range("A" & lRow).Value = "'" & Format(DateAdd("S", i, aCell.Value), "HH:MM:SS")
          ScratchPad.Range("B" & lRow).Value = aCell.Address
          ScratchPad.Range("C" & lRow).Value = i
      Next i
    Next aCell
    With Application
      .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Debug.Print Now()
    MsgBox "Load Call Times Done"
End Function
```

You can adjust the columns read in the code (currently F & G which I used for testing purposes. There is a more elegant solution using an array in code, which would run faster, but I had difficulty with Excels rendering of seconds which made matching on the decimal value (e.g.  0.3334837963 for 8:00:13) so I went with the lazy approach. The value of using an array vs. listing time apart from speed is the ability to only report the top-n values once the array is populated. If you love puzzles and get a sense of accomplishment from solving them think about how you might use a two dimensional array to increment the values for each second of the day. It's a fun challenge for those of us with apparently too much free time on our hands.  ;-)

Enjoy.